# Setup phpmyadmin with netbeans in mac os

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I am new in java development i am setting up netbeans with phpmyadmin for mysql connection, after referring tutorials i have set the connection as shown:

[Error here](http://s13.postimg.org/ptx72xjvb/Screen_Shot_2015_09_16_at_6_35_24_pm.png)
[admin Properties setup](http://postimg.org/image/xi7j1j84r/)

This is the error log which i am getting(sorry if its not useful):

```
2015-09-16 18:24:52 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

2015-09-16 18:24:52 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-5.6.26-osx10.8-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.26) starting as process 22744 ...
2015-09-16 18:24:52 22744 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.26-osx10.8-x86_64/data/Niravs-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
2015-09-16 18:24:52 22744 [Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.26-osx10.8-x86_64/data/Niravs-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
2015-09-16 18:24:52 22744 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use type TIMESTAMP not only DATE.

Comment: but where am i suppose to add that?

Answer (score 0):

You need set your path to the location of your `index.php` file in your phpmyadmin folder.

Something like this `/Users/macair/Sites/phpmyadmin/index.php`